# Convert EML to MSG - Java

Tags: java, aspose, msg, eml

I want to read the attachments from an EML file. . I prefer converting the EML file to an MSG file so I can re-use the written code, is this possible? If not, is there a way reading attachments from an EML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If not, is there a way reading attachments from an EML file?

[JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/) supports reading EML files (MIME-type `message/rfc822`). See the example [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0458.html).

Then extract attachments [like this](https://github.com/javaee/javamail/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/msgshow.java#L321). See also [this explanation](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#readattach).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Aspose.Email API to achieve both i.e. EML to MSG conversion and extracting attachments from EML.

**Extracting Attachments from EML**

```
//Initialize and Load an existing EML file
MailMessage msg = MailMessage.load(dataDir + "EmailWithAttachment.eml", new EmlLoadOptions());

//Initialize AttachmentCollection object with MailMessage Attachments
AttachmentCollection attachments = msg.getAttachments();

//Iterate over the AttachmentCollection
for (int index = 0; index < attachments.size(); index++) {
    //Initialize Attachment object and Get the indexed Attachment reference
    Attachment attachment = (Attachment) attachments.get_Item(index);
    //Display Attachment Name
    System.out.println(attachment.getName());
    //Save Attachment to disk
    attachment.save(dataDir + "attachment_" + attachment.getName());
}
```

**Converting EML to MSG**

```
// Initialize and Load an existing EML file by specifying the MessageFormat
MailMessage eml = MailMessage.load(dataDir + "test.eml");
//Save the Email message to disk in Unicode format
eml.save(dataDir + "LoadingEMLSavingToMSG_out.msg", SaveOptions.getDefaultMsgUnicode());
```

You can further visit [Working with MIME Messages](https://docs.aspose.com/display/emailjava/Working+with+MIME+Messages) for further information in this regard.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.